# Android StartActivityWithResult does not invoke onActivityWithResult

Tags: android

I had already read many posts regarding the onActivityWithResult not invoked. However, I still wasn't able to get a solution.

The Idea of my program is extremely simple: Activity A calls Activity B to get address and name of a Bluetooth device. I haven't tested out the bluetooth functionality yet, since the emulator does not support bluetooth, I'm just calling get bluetooth device which return a null indicating that I do not have a bluetooth available. If so, then I return to Activity A and gives a toast to tell the user that you don't have bluetooth enabled.

Activity A:

```
OnClickListener myButtonListener2 = new OnClickListener()
{
    public void onClick(View v) 
    {
        startActivityForResult(new Intent("bluetooth_4.pack.BluetoothSettings"), request_bluetooth_code);

        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Switching to Bluetooth Setting" , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
};
```

The onActivityCode:

```
public void onActivituResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
{
    if(requestCode == request_bluetooth_code)
    {
        if(resultCode == RESULT_OK)
        {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, data.getData().toString() , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            String[] split = data.getData().toString().split("@");
            BluetoothAddress = split[0];
            BluetoothName = split[1];
        }
        else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED)
        {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "You cancelled the activity, or you did not have any bluetooth opened" , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}
```

Basically what should happen is since the resultCode is cancelled, it should make a toast and the user will see it. However, I put a breakpoint on the if statement and tried to debug but it did not hit the breakpoint.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Button button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    Button button2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Connect);
    Button button3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);
    Button button4 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button4);

    button1.setOnClickListener(myButtonListener1);
    button2.setOnClickListener(myButtonListener2);
    button3.setOnClickListener(myButtonListener3);
    button4.setOnClickListener(myButtonListener4);

    ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
    actionBar.hide();
}
```

Activity B:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.bluetooth_main);

    Button button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    Button button2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);

    button1.setOnClickListener(myButtonListener1);
    button1.setOnClickListener(myButtonListener2);

    ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
    actionBar.hide();

    this.

    //Get a handle of the local bluetooth adapter
    mBtAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();

    if(mBtAdapter == null)
    {
        Toast.makeText(BluetoothSettings.this, "Your Bluetooth Is Closed, how will this thing work when your bluetooth is closed???" , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        setResult(RESULT_CANCELED, null);
        noBluetooth = true;
        finish();
    }

    BluetoothSettings someClass = new BluetoothSettings();

    ListView lstView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
    lstView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_checked, deviceListArray));
}
```

The code should stop at the if statement at Activity B, because no adapter is found.

Other functions at activity B:

```
protected void onDestroy() 
{
    //When we no longer have this activity, we cancel the discovery
    super.onDestroy();
    if (mBtAdapter != null) 
    {
        mBtAdapter.cancelDiscovery();
    }
}

public void onStop() 
{
    super.onStop();
    if(noBluetooth == false)
    {
        BroadcastReceiver localBroadcastReceiver = mReceiver;
        unregisterReceiver(localBroadcastReceiver);
    }
}
```

This is my manifest file:

```
    <activity
        android:name="MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity android:name="BluetoothSettings" 
              android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="bluetooth_4.pack.BluetoothSettings" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

I tried to debug the program, and the onActivityResult does not get called, does anybody know why? Thanks.

Comment: What is your onActivityResult  code in ACtivity A?

Comment: Sorry I forgot to put it in, it is now updated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think this is the answer to your question, buuuuut calling `finish()` does not stop the code outside of the `if` from executing. You need to add a `return;` after the call to `finish()` for the code to actually stop.

```
if(mBtAdapter == null)
{
    Toast.makeText(BluetoothSettings.this, "Your Bluetooth Is Closed, how will this thing work when your bluetooth is closed???" , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    setResult(RESULT_CANCELED, null);
    noBluetooth = true;
    finish();  
    return; //<----- like this. You can also wrap the other code in an else block.
}

BluetoothSettings someClass = new BluetoothSettings();

ListView lstView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
lstView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_checked, deviceListArray));
```

However, I just saw that you edited it and added some more code, and there might be a typo in your declaration of `onActivityResult()`:

```
 public void onActivituResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
 {...}
```

That says activitU not activitY

When you're trying to override a method it's useful to use the  `@Override` annotation. Adding that will warn you when you are actually *not* overriding anything.

Comment: Thank you so much, I actually spent half a day trying different solutions. I've seen a lot of @Override but I never knew what is their purpose.